# MO is not the place for Mochizuki news

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232087/have-there-been-any-updates-on-mochizukis-proposed-proof-of-the-abc-conjecture)

Everybody wants to know what's going on with this but we should leave it to Twitter, Reddit, blogs, etc. There is very little actual Mathematics in the discussion I linked to.

(I am supposed to ask a question) Why not?

Comment: I guess this should be tagged ([meta-tag:on-topic]) - since it is a discussion whether questions like that are suitable for this site or not. I was also thinking about ([meta-tag:specific-question]) , I am not sure whether it's a good fit - the question is probably more about one specific topic that tied to one particular question (the one linked in the post).

Comment: Regarding the remark "leave it to Twitter, Reddit, blogs, ...", I'll just remind that [MathOverflow has its own chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369) and on Mathematics there is [Number Theory room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12070) - but neither of them is visited vary often.

Answer (score 11):

I see a reasonable amount of mathematics in the answers, together with links to relevant discussions and papers.

I think the question is not about gossip, and it is a valuable service to mathematicians who are not themselves experts in the relevant topic such as myself.

I should probably add that I find the topic of obvious mathematical interest, and the links and surrounding discussion useful. The gossip, not so much.